# Gravar o resultado de uma variável no banco de dados Mysql usando python passado como parametro

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

Tenho um banco de dados em `mysql` que contém uma tabela com várias expressões. Eu consigo extrair as expressões através de uma `procedure`, resolvê-las, porém quando quero devolver o valor do cálculo para o banco com outra `procedure`, esse valor não é gravado. Segue o código abaixo:

```
    # mysql = MySQLdb.connect(host = "localhost", user = "client", passwd = "123456", db = "sist_dist")
    mysql = MySQLdb.connect('192.168.252.30','client','123456','sist_dist')
    mysql_cursor = mysql.cursor()
    mysql_cursor.execute("call retira_exp('mangaba')")

    linha_expressao = mysql_cursor.fetchone()


    if linha_expressao=="":
        sys.exit()

    expressao_banco = linha_expressao[1]
    id_expressao = linha_expressao[0]


    resultado = eval(expressao_banco)

    print  resultado

    mysql_cursor = mysql.cursor()
    mysql_cursor.execute("CALL entrega_res('id_expressao','resultado')")
```

Comment: @mgibsonbr você pode ajudar?

Comment: Fernando, não acho que ele receba alguma notificação, ele precisa interagir com a pergunta para que isso aconteça. Só ai você usa o `@`.

Comment: primeira vez usando, tô meio perdido nesse tipo de coisa.

Comment: e voce Florida poderia me dar uma força?

Comment: Desculpe, esta muito além dos meus conhecimentos, o melhor que você pode fazer é aguardar pacientemente.

Comment: brigado mesmo assim.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu entendi, sua dificuldade é em passar variáveis para sua consulta SQL, certo? O comando [`execute`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) possui um parâmetro `params` que recebe uma tupla/lista ou dicionário. Nele você associa índices ou nomes de variáveis aos seus valores de fato:

```
valores = (id_expressao, resultado)
mysql_cursor.execute("CALL entrega_res(%s,%s)", valores)
```

Ou:

```
valores = {
    "id_expressao":id_expressao,
    "resultado":resultado,
}
mysql_cursor.execute("CALL entrega_res(%{id_expressao}s,%{resultado}s)", valores)
```

(na minha opinião, a primeira é mais curta e simples; use a segunda só se você precisar usar o mesmo valor duas vezes na mesma consulta)

Isso deve passar os valores corretamente pra sua chamada. A partir daí, você precisa se certificar que o *stored procedure* `entrega_res` faça o que tem que fazer (como você não postou seu código, não tem como nós te ajudarmos com ela, caso ela possua algum problema).

Comment: Brigadão Marcelo, agora ta rodando filé, porém não está gravando as informações ficando como NULL.                                                              CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `entrega_res`(
IN id_temp INT, resultado_temp VARCHAR(400)
)
BEGIN
UPDATE tb_expressoes
SET resultado = resultado_temp, horario_entrega = NOW()
WHERE id = id_temp;
END